# Incorrect behaviour of Google Translation API with notranslate tags

Tags: google-translate, google-translation-api, google-cloud-automl

Google Translate API allows indicating chunks of text that should not be translated with

```
<span translate='no'>Skip this text while translating</span>
```

In some cases there is an incorrect behaviour with non-translate tags, that causes the translation API to omit one of the words and to duplicate the non-translate tag. Input of the translation API:

```
0c40152c asdasd alsdls3 ec3f297a <span translate="no">AAAAA123AAAA</span> Nov 30 translate
```

When translating from Italian to English (not sure if the language matters), the following result is returned:

```
0c40152c asdasd alsdls3 ec3f297a <span translate="no">AAAAA123AAAA</span> Nov 30 <span translate="no">AAAAA123AAAA</span>
```

Please note that the 'translate' at the end of the text is substituted with the non-translate tag.
This issues are present if instead of `<span translate='no'>` I use the alternative syntax: `<span class='notranslate'>`.

Is this a known bug ? Does it have a sensible workaround ?

Answer (score 1):

#### Is this a known bug?

Yes: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/121076288

> #### Translation problem with notranslate class in span tag
>
> Problem you have encountered:
>   The translation API gives wrong results translating from german to arabic
>
> German text:
>   QANTARA Migration - Kostenfreie Erstprüfung Ihrer Chancen für die erfolgreiche Immigration nach Deutschland
>
> Arabic translation:
>   QANTARA Migration - إجراء فحص أولي مجاني لفرص نجاح QANTARA Migration إلى ألمانيا
>
> What you expected to happen:
>   Correct translation without doubling the span with notranslate - this was doubled in arabic translation as you can see

There are also a few others that seem related, like https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/74168658 and https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35902695.

#### Does it have a sensible workaround?

Only hacky ones, I'm afraid.

The easiest workaround is just to replace such sections with a token, like a unique number or url that Translate is smart enough not to touch, translate, then swap the original string back in.

A more general solution is to use something like [ModelFront](https://modelfront.com) (full-disclosure: I work there) to detect errors, and do something only in those cases.

Answer (score -2):

It seems like you have specified Italian as input language, but there are very few words in the text which can be translated (for example “translate”) and they are not recognised in the source language.
This can derivate in issues with the translation algorithm, which seems to be the case here.

A workaround would be setting the source language to get [automatically detected](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/detecting-language) by the API and checking the [confidence value](https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/translate/usage.html):

> The confidence value is an optional floating point value between 0 and
>   1. The closer this value is to 1, the higher the confidence level for the language detection. This member is not always available

If the confidence value is high enough for your needs, it will try to detect the appropriate source language to translate from.

Another workaround could be adding more words to the text so the algorithm has more data to work with. [I have tested the API](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/translate/v2/language.translations.list?q=0c40152c%20asdasd%20alsdls3%20ec3f297a%20%253Cspan%20translate%253D%2522no%2522%253EAAAAA123AAAA%253C%252Fspan%253E%20Nov%2030%20translate%20home%20boat%20&target=en&source=it&_h=1&)  with the same input as you describe but adding a few more words. The result output is the expected.

Comment: The problem is that it is possible for the translate api to add a non-translatable token twice in the result. Of course the example is fake and of course it will be OK if you change some words in it. Also, sometimes you want to translate text or text with English words in it.